# problem when retrieving files from cloud storage using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

I want to retrieve a JSON file from cloud storage using pyspark.

I'm running Spark in standalone by running from the `spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3` binaries the commands :
`./start-master.sh`
`./start-slave.sh spark://MacBook-User.local:7077`

In my bucket I have a "test.json" object as follows:
[image: my_bucket]

My python script test2.py is the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType

appName = "PySpark Example - Read JSON file from GCS"

# Create Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(appName) \
    .getOrCreate()

# Setup hadoop fs configuration for schema gs://
conf = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")

# Create a schema for the dataframe
schema = StructType([
    StructField('ID', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('ATTR1', StringType(), True)
])

# Create data frame
json_file_path = 'gs://testpysparkscript/test.json'
df = spark.read.json(json_file_path, schema, multiLine=True)
print(df.schema)
df.show()
```

To execute my python script I run the following command:

```
spark-submit \
  --master spark://MacBook-User.local:7077 \
  --deploy-mode client \
  test2.py
```

However I get the following error:

```
    23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.3.2
23/04/24 11:16:15 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: PySpark Example - Read JSON file from GCS
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: user1
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: user1
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(user1); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(user1); groups with modify permissions: Set()
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 50591.
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/lq/nl1_hy_j0699dnt63l8fcnym0000gp/T/blockmgr-e213b856-503a-4f30-ba9b-2f8751d5a470
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 434.4 MiB
23/04/24 11:16:15 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://MacBook-User.local:7077...
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to MacBook-User.local/192.168.1.37:7077 after 26 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20230424111616-0001
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20230424111616-0001/0 on worker-20230424102858-192.168.1.37-49564 (192.168.1.37:49564) with 8 core(s)
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20230424111616-0001/0 on hostPort 192.168.1.37:49564 with 8 core(s), 1024.0 MiB RAM
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 50594.
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.1.37:50594
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.37, 50594, None)
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.37:50594 with 434.4 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.37, 50594, None)
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.37, 50594, None)
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.37, 50594, None)
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20230424111616-0001/0 is now RUNNING
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
23/04/24 11:16:16 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/Users/user1/Projects/Perso/ingestionLocally/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/bin/spark-warehouse'.
23/04/24 11:16:17 WARN FileStreamSink: Assume no metadata directory. Error while looking for metadata directory in the path: gs://testpysparkscript/test.json.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:361)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)
    ... 26 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/Projects/Perso/ingestionLocally/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/bin/test2.py", line 24, in <module>
    df = spark.read.json(json_file_path, schema, multiLine=True)
  File "/Users/user1/Projects/Perso/ingestionLocally/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 284, in json
  File "/Users/user1/Projects/Perso/ingestionLocally/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "/Users/user1/Projects/Perso/ingestionLocally/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
  File "/Users/user1/Projects/Perso/ingestionLocally/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o33.json.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1(DataSource.scala:752)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:750)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:579)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:361)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)
    ... 29 more

23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.37:4040
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/lq/nl1_hy_j0699dnt63l8fcnym0000gp/T/spark-da7c000f-146d-4be9-a68e-fb8d8db86e9e
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/lq/nl1_hy_j0699dnt63l8fcnym0000gp/T/spark-2b828179-25c5-4abe-9039-1bb8f17a7ea1
23/04/24 11:16:18 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/lq/nl1_hy_j0699dnt63l8fcnym0000gp/T/spark-2b828179-25c5-4abe-9039-1bb8f17a7ea1/pyspark-ac79381e-a738-4ee0-b777-8aaeda307794
```

Can you help me to resolve this problem please ?

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In the link it is written that "Placing the connector jar in the HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_JARS_DIR directory should be sufficient to have Hadoop load the jar. Alternatively, to be certain that the jar is loaded, you can add HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:</path/to/gcs-connector.jar> to hadoop-env.sh in the Hadoop configuration directory."

So I downloaded gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.2-shaded.jar. But where can I find the HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_JARS_DIR directory ?